# Fetching only shipped orders from orocommerce using API

Tags: orocommerce

I want to fetch orders with the internal status shipped from my orocommerce store what will be filter for that.In documentation I am not getting any help.
Thanks
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 1):

Seems entity InternalStatus is disabled by default – https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/OrderBundle/Resources/config/oro/api.yml#L37.

If you change (overwrite in your api.yml) it to:

```
Extend\Entity\EV_Order_Internal_Status: ~
```

it will be available in API in relationships section:

```
"internal_status": ▿{
          "data": {
            "type": "orderinternalstatuses",
            "id": "open"
          }
        }
      }
```

as well as in filter. For other entities same configuration should be applied.

Please have a look at API documentation – https://github.com/laboro/dev/blob/f2a40c66127531287b4f0d5a35ed7800196be6ac/package/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/ApiBundle/Resources/doc/configuration.md

Comment: I have modified it like this but still not working  Extend\Entity\EV_Order_Internal_Status: ~
            actions: false

Comment: Have you executed commands as described:

Important: Run the oro:api:cache:clear CLI command to immediately make an entity accessible via the data API. If you use the API sandbox, run the oro:api:doc:cache:clear CLI command to apply the changes for it.